# Make Postfix use MySQL to check whether sender adress is permitted

Tags: mysql, email, postfix

We're trying to use PostFix to check whether the sender email-address is permitted to send to a specific email-address.

Another way to describe it would be that I want specific e-mailaddresses to only allow incoming messages (not SMTP logins) from specific e-mailaddresses.

Will something like this work?
main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    [other restrictions here]
    check_sender_access
        mysql:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders_to_recipents.cf
```

restricted_senders_to_recipents.cf:

```
user = uname
password = pword
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = dbname
#!!!PSEUDOCODE!!!
query = SELECT allowed FROM members WHERE sender = %sender AND recipent = %recipent;
```

Is this possible? If then how?

I know that aliases with MySQL works this way since we're already using it. (http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html)

Comment: It should work. Is that your question?

Comment: Yes. But is there a sender variable in PostFix? I know there's a recipent one to look up aliases.

Comment: @emilhem have you gotten any idea for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We now use Sympa as our mail list system. It works good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is PROBABLY NO.

Postfix supports per sender/recipient/client restriction with [Postfix Per-Client/User/etc. Access Control](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html) with `smtpd_restriction_classes`. With your requirement, you must dynamically set `smtpd_restriction_classes` parameter, but it doesn't work with postfix.

As workaround, you could use Milter (See [the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html)) or something like [Postfwd](http://postfwd.org/) or [PolicyD](http://www.policyd.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can accomplish this in a two part process.

First, create a smtpd_sender_restriction that is a mysql lookup for addresses who bleong to the class of users who need the acl:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    ...
    mysql:/etc/postfix/protected_users.cf
```

Next, because that mysql lookup will return a class of users, you can assign that class of users to do anohter lookup to decide if the mail can be sent:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    ...
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/protected_users.cf
```

whitelist = check_sender_access proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/whitelist.cf, reject

This two part lookup should do what you need.

[Reference](https://://www.linux.com/news/child-safe-smtp-whitelist-postfix-and-mysql-0)